# rsyslog conf file syntax multiple filters

Tags: redhat, rsyslog

I'm setting up rsyslog on a Red Hat 8 system. I have the the first part working, that filters based on source IP, and writes logs in a specific file, like this:

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' then /var/log/test_all.log
& ~
```

What I'd like to do, that I cannot figure out the correct syntax for, is to check for the **host IP** and the **authpriv** facility and write it to a file.

I know, that I need that statement before the one I listed above, but I can't get it to work. I've also tried the `local7` (boot logs) and that didn't work either. The next two examples are syntaxes I tried which didn't work:

Example 1:

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' and $syslogfacility-text == 'local7' then /var/log/test_boot.log
& stop

if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' and $syslogfacility-text == 'local10' then /var/log/test_secure.log
& stop

if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' then /var/log/test_all.log
& stop
```

Example 2:

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' and $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv.*' then /var/log/test_secure.log
& stop

if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' then /var/log/test_all.log
& stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here:
[rsyslog configuration syntax](https://serverfault.com/questions/633708/rsyslog-configuration-syntax?rq=1)

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.1.2.45' then { 

    authpriv.*  -/var/log/test_secure.log
                -/var/log/test_all.log
    & stop
}
```